# How to count nested parenthesis without match?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I'm trying to count the total mismatched parenthesis.

```
input:  text = “(()”
output: 1

input:  text = “(())”
output: 0

input:  text = “())(”
output: 2
```

I have tried the following, but it doesn't work:

```js
let isMatchingBrackets = function(str) {
  let stack = [];
  let count = 0;

  for (let i in str.length) {
    if (str[i] === "(") {
      stack.push(str[i])
    } else if (str[i] === ")") {
      let tem = map.stack(x => x)
      if (tem !== ")") {
        count += 1;
      } else {
        stack.pop();
      }
    }
  }

  return stack.length + count
}

console.log(isMatchingBrackets("(()"))
console.log(isMatchingBrackets("(())"))
console.log(isMatchingBrackets("())("))
```

Comment: What type of idea are you looking for? Is your code not working or are you not getting expected output or are you looking for better approaches?

Comment: What is `map.stack(x => x)` supposed to do? Where is the `map` object?

Comment: Did you mean `stack.map(x => x)`? A simpler way to copy an array is with `temp = stack.slice()`

Comment: `for (let i in str.length)` makes no sense. `str.length` isn't an object .

Comment: my bad its typo , Yes  i meant Stack.map()

Comment: The length property returns the length of a string

Comment: @NavidYousefzai Yes, that's what `length` returns. But `for (variable in value)` iterates through the all the properties of the value, it doesn't iterate to a number.

Comment: `if (tem !== ")")` also makes little sense. `tem` is an array, it will never be equal to a string.

Comment: You want `for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++)`

Comment: I can't figure out what logic you're trying to implement with `if (tem !== ")")`.

Comment: here is the Pseudocode: 
    diffCounter = 0
    ans = 0
    n = text.length

    for i from 0 to n-1:
        if ( text[i] == '(' ):
            diffCounter += 1
        else if ( text[i] == ')' ):
            diffCounter -= 1
        if ( diffCounter < 0 ):
            diffCounter += 1
            ans += 1

    return ans + diffCounter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, your iteration is wrong. You need to use `for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++)` to iterate a series of indexes.

Next, `if (tem !=== ")")` makes no sense, since an array can never be equal to a string. What you want to check is whether the stack is empty. If you have a `)` with an empty stack, it means it's mismatched.

There's no need for the `tem` variable.

```js
let isMatchingBrackets = function(str) {
  let stack = [];
  let count = 0;

  for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if (str[i] === "(") {
      stack.push(str[i])
    } else if (str[i] === ")") {
      if (stack.length === 0) {
        count += 1;
      } else {
        stack.pop();
      }
    }
  }

  return stack.length + count
}

console.log(isMatchingBrackets("(()"))
console.log(isMatchingBrackets("(())"))
console.log(isMatchingBrackets("())("))
```

But you don't really need a stack at all. You just need to count the number of opening parentheses, and decrement that counter whenever you get a matching close parenthesis.

```js
let isMatchingBrackets = function(str) {
  let open_count = 0;
  let close_count = 0;

  for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if (str[i] === "(") {
      open_count++;
    } else if (str[i] === ")") {
      if (open_count === 0) {
        close_count ++;
      } else {
        open_count--;
      }
    }
  }

  return open_count + close_count;
}

console.log(isMatchingBrackets("(()"))
console.log(isMatchingBrackets("(())"))
console.log(isMatchingBrackets("())("))
```

Answer (score 2):

If you just need a count of the mismatches, it suffices to keep a trace of the nesting level, `+1` for a left parenthesis, `-1` for right:

```
( ( )
 1 2 1

( ( ) )
 1 2 1 0

( ) ) (
 1 0-1 0
```

Negative values are anomalies, as is a final nonzero.

Comment: totally, I think I got it now

Answer (score 0):

I didn't check with the syntax but the algorithm should be correct

I would suggest this

```
for (let i in str.length) {
    if (str[i] === "(") {
        stack.push(str[i])
    } else if (str[i] === ")") {
        if (stack.length > 0) {
           stack.pop();
        } else {
           count++;
        }
    }
}
return stack.length + count;
```

But if you don't want to change it then

```
let tem = map.stack(x => x)
if (tem !== ")") {
    count += 1;
} else {
    stack.pop();
}
```

The error is that the if statment should be tem !== '(' and you should pop if you find it as well

Answer (score 0):

Just another attempt. Not well tested though.

```js
let text = [
  "(()",  //output: 1
  "(())", //output: 0
  "())(", //output: 2
]

result = ""
text.forEach(t => {
  let originalText = t
  for(let i = 0; i < t.length; i){
    if (t[i] === '('){
      if (t.indexOf(')') > -1){
        t = t.replace(t[i], '')
        t = t.replace(')', '')
      }
      else {
        result += t[i]
        t = t.replace(t[i], '')
      }
    }
    if (t[i] === ')'){
      result += t[i]
      t = t.replace(t[i], '')
    }
  }
  console.log(originalText, result.length)
  result = ""
})
```

Answer (score 0):

after a few years of experience:)

```
  const isMatchingBrackets = (str)=> {
  let stack = [];
  let mismatchCount = 0;

  for (let char of str) {
    if (char === '(') {
      stack.push(char);
    } else if (char === ')') {
      if (stack.length > 0) {
        stack.pop();
      } else {
        mismatchCount++;
      }
    }
  }

  return stack.length + mismatchCount;
}
```